# JQuery/javascript how do I get the ID of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function cat() {


    this.getMyID = function() { alert(this.id); } ;

}

var bob = new cat();

// I want it to say 'bob'
bob.getMyID();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7eHj/

alerts undefined, any ideas?

I'll elaborate, this is what I want to do - insert into an onclick method of a button something that calls another function, eg:

```
function cat() {

   this.render = function() { $('#myButton').attr('onclick', 'this.meow()'); };

}

var bob = new cat();
bob.render();
```

However this will fail because 'this.meow' is nonsense. If I knew the ID, ie. bob, then I could change it to do `.attr('onclick', theID + '.meow()'); };`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Potentially, the answer!

Comment: @SLC: Please explain how you think jQuery is related? There's not a single line of jQuery in your code

Comment: @Juan I have included the JQuery library, and a JQuery solution would be acceptable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the reference name of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827731/get-the-reference-name-of-an-object)

Comment: @SLC: Your problem has nothing to do with jQuery, JS objects don't have an id property unless you create one.

Comment: There is no default "id" property for an object. You can for example add one using some algorithm in the constructor, like using some static incriment.

Comment: @Felix Thanks that answers it, you have to pass it as a parameter!

Comment: @SLC: No, have a look at your my answer (I just voted to close before you made your edit). Your problem can be solved in an other (cleaner) way.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your update:

Assuming `cat` has a method `meow`, you should do the following:

```
function Cat() {
   var that = this;
   this.render = function() { 
       $('#myButton').click(function() {
           that.meow();
       });
   };
}

// assuming it exists something like
Cat.prototype.meow = function() {/*...*/};
```

You already have a reference to the object (`this`), you don't need to know in which variable it is stored.

You should also use jQuery's `click` function to assign a click handler. But be careful though as this would add a new click handler every time you call `render()`.

Answer (score 1):

Generic "objects" don't have IDs - they don't know what variables are bound to them.

Furthermore you could have said:

```
var bob = new cat();
var alice = bob;
```

at which point you have a schizophrenic cat.

Answer (score 0):

It alerts `undefined`  because cat doesn't have an "id" property. No sure how you expected it to have an id.

Answer (score 0):

I will try...

> I'll elaborate, this is what I want to
>   do - insert into an onclick method of
>   a button something that calls another
>   function,

Here is some code... is it close?

```
var bobthefunction = function () {
    // do crazy stuff
   }

$("buttonname").attr("onclick",bobthefunction);
```

or

```
$("buttonname").click(bobthefunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use closures:

```
function cat() {
    this.render = function() 
    { 
        $('#myButton').click(function(self ) 
        {
            return function() { self.meow() }
        }(this));
    }
}
```

By the way, it's not recommended to attach event handlers using .attr - it simply doesn't always work in all browsers/cases. You better use .bind or an even shortcut like .click

Comment: a self calling function that passes in arguments is not very easy to read, specially for people who haven't seen that pattern. Like others have mentioned, it's easier to store this as a closure variable that can be accessed by the inner handlers. In your case, you would just do `var self = this;` just before calling `this.render = function()`

Comment: @Andrey : I hope you did not miss understand -- I was not saying it was wrong or there was a better way to do it... just that it hurt my brain.

Comment: @Juan - you are right; I'm so used to "static" objects where I need to use closures because I can't have closure variables, that I overlooked the obvious here

Comment: @Hogan - I know, it used to heart my brain too, until I had to use closures for couple thousand times; now it's like reading kids' book :)